# How to check if a window handle is for a console window?

Tags: c#, windows, interop

I have an application, using one process, that has two windows. Both these windows have the same title. One is the main app window, that the user does all their interaction with. The other is a console window which is used purely for live logging of commands executed in the main window.

I'm currently implementing a Mutex and if the application is open already, I want to restore & switch to the currently running main application window (not the console window). However, given that both windows have the same title and the same process, it's proven hard to distinguish between the two.

Is there a way to determine if a window is a console window? Or any other way to distinguish between these two windows?

Comment: Have you tried GetClassName?  Alternatively, you could set a custom property on your main window using SetProp.